# Log4J XML Strip first character from ${web:contextPath}

Tags: xml, logging, log4j2

I am wondering if there is a way to get a substring from a system property, or format one so as to strip the first character only through the XML configuration?  The problem I am having is with the `DefaultRolloverStrategy`'s `Delete` feature.  I have the following code:

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="31">
    <Delete basePath="${sys:log.location}" maxDepth="1">
        <IfFileName glob="${web:contextPath}-*.log" />
        <IfLastModified age="90d" />
    </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

However, in my logs, I can see that this value `${web:contextPath}-*.log` gets interpreted as `/Meanwhile-In-Hell-App1-*.log`, with the first character being `/`.  This doesn't delete any old files, as this value is relative to the `basePath` (with some experimenting, I have found that if I hard-code the glob to `Meanwhile-In-Hell-App1-*.log`, it deletes the old logs successfully.  However, I cannot rely on this method, so must be read from `${web:contextPath}`).  I have also tried using the slash and adding a dot before it, since the path is supposed to be relative.  But this again, does not delete the old files.

I am using log4j2 version 2.8.

Comment: how about removing `basePath` attribute and setting `<IfFileName glob="${sys:log.location}${web:contextPath}-*.log" />` ?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't think of that.  I'll give that try!  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if it worked please.

Comment: Yes, that did it @LuisMuñoz!

Comment: You can accept the answer then :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove basePath attribute and set

`<IfFileName glob="${sys:log.location}${web:contextPath}-*.log" />`